# Separating multiple mixed signal source from single measurement?

Tags: matlab, statistics, signal-processing

Is it possible to separate out multiple mixed sources from a single measurement. I saw that Blind source separation (BSS) using Independent component analysis (ICA) does it for MIMO system. But what about the MISO system. Does any one suggest any article or Matlab code for this type of problem?

Comment: This is called "underdetermined BSS", and there are a lot of algorithms available for that. But you should be more specific on what kind of signals you want to seperate, because most of these algorithms rely on a signal model.

Comment: My signals are transient in nature. They are coming out due to the responses of RLC circuit.